# SVN tree conflict, modified working copy file in renamed directory, how to resolve?

Tags: svn

I have a working copy in which I have made changes to a file I wish to keep. In the repository the name of the directory (actually, a higher level directory) containing the file has been renamed. This means when I have updated there is a tree conflict as the file is marked for deletion.

Now, I can think of various workarounds in this case to allow me to keep my changes (such as checking out a new working copy and copying the file over etc.), but what is the 'correct' way to commit the local changes and resolve the conflict?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with SVN anymore but if the file is marked for deletion, does it mean the original directory has been deleted and re-created under a different name? If it has just been renamed, I'd expect it to get renamed when performing an update of your workspace as well.